# node child_process.spawn not working with spaces in path on windows

Tags: node.js

How to provide a path to `child_process.spawn`

For example the path:

`c:\users\marco\my documents\project\someexecutable`

The path is provided by the enduser from a configuration file.

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var path = require('path');
var pathToExecute = path.join(options.toolsPath, 'mspec.exe');
child_process.spawn(pathToExecute, options.args);
```

Currently only the part after the space is used by `child_process.spawn`

I also tried by adding quotes arround the path like this:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var path = require('path');
var pathToExecute = path.join(options.toolsPath, 'mspec.exe');
child_process.spawn('"' + pathToExecute + '"', options.args);
```

However this results in a `ENOENT` error.

Comment: What about using `path.join(path, path, ...)` to build the path for the `child_process.spawn`. That usually resolved that kind of issues.

Comment: ... also a bit of code showing how you use `child_process.spawn` would help.

Comment: @Tom I have updated my question and included some example code for both the scenario's I tried. OH: I'm totally sure the file is at this location. Can you help me further?

Comment: I tested your code on my local environment (obviously with different executable but that should not matter) and one thing which may be wrong (my first thought) is setting `c:\users\marco\my documents\project\someexecutable` path. In the code it should be like `options.toolsPath = "c:\\users\\marco\\my documents\\project\\someexecutable";` Can you confirm that you use \\ instead of \ in your code when setting up the path?

Comment: Another thing which caught my eye: is `someexecutable` from your path an executable which should be executed? But then you append `mspec.exe`. So I assume that your path is now `c:\\users\\marco\\my documents\\project` when you use `path.join` with `mspec.exe`.

Comment: @Tom you're right. The user provides the path. Based on other settings it takes the correct executable from the provided path. My code is on github. https://github.com/marcofranssen/grunt-dotnet-mspec.git

Comment: did you ever get this solved, i'm having the same issue

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.  Quotes don't fix it.  And escaping the spaces with backslashes don't work either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first parameter must be the command name, not the full path to the executable. There's an option called `cwd` to specify the working directory of the process, also you can make sure the executable is reachable adding it to your `PATH` variable (probably easier to do).

Also, the `args` array passed to `spawn` shouldn't contain empty elements.

You code should look something like this:

```
child_process.spawn('mspec.exe', options.args, {cwd: '...'});
```

Answer (score 7):

As per https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7367#issuecomment-229728704 one can use the `{ shell: true }` option.

For example

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn(process.env.comspec, ['/c', 'dir /b "C:\\users\\Trevor\\Documents\\Adobe Scripts"'],  { shell: true });
```

Will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `spawn` frequently, the way I solved the problem is to use `process.chdir`. So if your path is `c:\users\marco\my documents\project\someexecutable` then you should do the following:

```
process.chdir('C:\\users\\marco\\my documents\\project');
child_process.spawn('./myBigFile.exe', options.args);
```

Note the double `\`s, that's how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Escape space with \ too:

```bash
C:\\Program\ Files\\Common\ Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe
```